# How to convert two 8 digit decimal numbers to form an alphabetical or alphanumeric code

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am a newbie to android, I started working with maps and

My scenario is: Whenever I place a marker in the map it should generate a code(like pincode) for the place based in its latitude and longitude which might be alphanumeric

My problem is: When I fetch the latitute and longitude(eg:12.828435,80.218367) from a place I should convert them to possible smallest alphanumric code and display to user(eg:abcd4frt)

I don't know if this idea can be implemented the way I described above.

Please give me your ideas

Comment: Well, the easiest encoding is dropping the dot. Then its really just a problem of converting from base 10 to base 36.

Comment: ya its working but how to embed that algorithm into my android programming, do you have any idea regarding this?

Comment: you should try polyline encode/decode for that

Comment: Can you give me some link to study about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This answer assumes latitude and longitude to be represented as 8 digit decimals.**

The following will encode your longitude to base 36:

```
//convert longitude to an int, depending on what form it's in

String encodedLongitude = Integer.toString(longitude, 36);
```

And this will decode it back:

```
int longitude = Integer.valueOf(encodedLongitude, 36);

//convert longitude back to decimal.
```

To concatenate them together, you can probably just use any non-alphanumeric delimiter. You can't just jam them beside eachother, because the encoded strings are not always the same length.

Alternatively you could say:

```
long longLat = latitude + longitude * Math.pow(10, 8); //shift the longitude 8 places, and add to latitude

String encodedLongLat = Long.toString(longLat, 36);
```

Then to decode:

```
long longLat = Long.valueOf(encodedLongLat, 36);

long longitude = longLat / Math.pow(10, 8);
long latitude = longLat % Math.pow(10, 8);
```

Comment: Do I need to import any additional library to use this code?

Comment: @srujanmaddula Nope. This should all be standard library since JDK1.0